# Limiting options a user can select - OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am currently creating a settings page for my Mac Application in OS X. I want to present a few predetermined options to the user that they can select. For example, for their region ID they can either select North, South, East, or West. Is there I way I could present these options to the user and then determine what they selected? I tried searching for "predetermined options", "radio button for OS X", "scroll wheel", but I didn't come up with much. I am also not sure if there is some sort of name that everyone calls a predetermined list. If there is just let me know. I am kind of new to the Objective C game and this is my first OS X app. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Radio button(s)" is the term used, although it may help to search with "Cocoa" rather than "OS X". Using radio buttons in Cocoa is *slightly* more complicated than you might expect as a novice, since the radio buttons are usually organized within a matrix (`NSMatrix`). You could also use a pop-menu, a list (which is a simple table view), or some other UI.

A good place to start when deciding how to design your UI is Apple's [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Intro/Intro.html) document. There's a whole chapter on [controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Controls/Controls.html). There's also a separate document about buttons: [Button Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Button.html).

Comment: @Thomases Excellent, I will check those out. Thanks for the assistance.